Javascriptで変数に値を代入するための何かを別の変数に保存したい
タイトルがわかりづらくてすみません。
arr[0][0] = 1
みたいにすれば、arr[0][0]に１を代入できますが
arr[0][0]に ”値を代入するための何か” を以下のように別の変数に保存してスムーズに代入することはできますか？
(”何か”が何なのかは専門用語を知らないためわかりません)
b = 何か( arr[0][0] ) 
b = 1 //arr[0][0]に1が保存される。

普通に代入すると当然値が代入されてしまいます。
以下のような方法も考えましたが、この方法だと自分のやりたいことが部分的にできないためほかに方法があれば教えていただきたいです。
a[0][0] = [0]
b = a[0][0]
b[0] = 1


自分も詳しく無いですが、他の言語で言うところの「参照渡し」みたいなイメージでしょうか。 知ってるようで意外と知らない、JavaScriptの参照のしくみ

これです。参照渡しっていうんですね。

C++であれば、下記のようなコードのようなことがしたいと言うことでしょうか？
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[2][2] = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}};
    int& b = arr[0][0];
    cout << arr[0][0] << endl;
    b = 1;
    cout << arr[0][0] << endl;
    return 0;
}

JavaScriptに上のC++のような機能はありませんが、見た目だけなら、次のように書くと同じような動作をさせることができます。
const arr = [[0, 1], [2, 3]];
Object.defineProperty(globalThis, "b", {set: (v) => {arr[0][0] = v;}});
console.log(arr[0][0]);
b = 1;
console.log(arr[0][0]);

ただ、これはC++でやっていることとは全く別のことで、実際のところは下記とほとんど変わりません。
const arr = [[0, 1], [2, 3]];
const b = (v) => {arr[0][0] = v;};
console.log(arr[0][0]);
b(1);
console.log(arr[0][0]);

具体的にやりたいことが全体像がみえないのでなんとも言えませんが、絶対に「代入」という動作で無ければならない理由があると言うことが無ければ、上記のように関数にしてしまえばいいかと思います。

ご回答ありがとうございます。関数化すると処理が少し遅くなってしまうかと思って試していなかったのですが、関数でやってみることにします。
